# Tips to write more readable code

Tags: programming, code-review

What are some tips to write a more readable code?

For example in C, tab is your friend. You can also declare variables in a way such that you can read the code easily later on.

In Mathematica, if you are writing a complicated code, things can get messy very quick and becomes very hard to read later on. What are some tips for code readability without trading away the performance?

Comment: check out [Programming Mathematica in plaintext, i.e. no formatting, non-notebook](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31040/programming-mathematica-in-plaintext-i-e-no-formatting-non-notebook)

Comment: @commentators I don't think this is broader than *Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?*. I find the question ***very*** interesting and would vote to remove the hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several rules of thumb:

- Always use lower-case letters to start the name of a variable or defined function:  `myList` and `myFunction` (not `MyList` or `MyFunction`) so as to never conflict with *Matheamtica*'s internal names.
- Group similar program elements on a single line for readability:

`Plot3D[Sin[x y],
   {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,1}]`

instead of

`Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 
    1}, {y, 0,1}]`

- Likewise, align lists, options, and such so that any errors can be easily seen
- Use blank lines to separate large groups of code of similar functionality.
- Use the `usage` option for important functions, as in `f::usage = "explanation of function f"`
- Comment as necessary `(* my comment *)`
- There are innumerable other suggestions that are specific to *Mathematica* language (such as `Table` instead of `Do`) that are best discovered by extensive programming.
- Use cell style such as `Chapter` to separate code in easily recognizable fashion.
- Use the pulldown menu `Format... TextColor` or `Format... BackgroundColor` to color variables or functions for ease of finding and reading.

Comment: Thank you, this is about what I am asking.

Answer (score 4):

In any programming language the readability of code is greatly improved when the programmer takes the time and puts in the effort to use meaningful identifiers.  *Mathematica* is no exception in this regard.

I quote a piece of own code as an example. It moves a file into the OS X trash.

```
moveToTrash[fullPathName_String] :=
  Module[{trash, fileName},
    trash = FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[], ".Trash"}];
    fileName = FileNameTake[fullPathName];
    While[FileExistsQ[FileNameJoin[{trash, fileName}]],fileName = "#" <> fileName];
    RenameFile[fullPathName, FileNameJoin[{trash, fileName}]]]
```

I think this code is as readable as any code written with care given to choosing identifier names in any other language.

Answer (score 3):

In a language like C, you'll write sequential procedures like:

> a=some stuff;
>
> b=more stuff;
>
> result=munge a and b together;
>
> return result;

In Mathematica, it's much handier to write one-line functions and compose them rather than one-line steps and concatenate them:

```
a[stuff_]:=a formula

b[stuff_]:=another formula

munge[stuff_]:=a[stuff] together with b[stuff]
```

By making a, b, and munge functions, you localize their behavior and make them easier to understand and test in isolation.